# Size of the button (leaflet search plugin)

Tags: javascript, css, button, size, leaflet

I got a map with a button created using the plugin leaflet control search, I've just followed the demos to add it.

I also have few buttons created with easybutton plugin.

When I use Firefox they look fine, all the same size, but with chrome or edge the search control button is smaller than the rest, actually the other buttons are bigger while the one created with leaflet.search.control is smaller.

I tried to create it through easy.buttons but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
layer: Hospitals,
propertyName: 'Hosp_Name',
zoom:14,
hideMarkerOnCollapse:true,
textPlaceholder: "Search Hospital"
});
searchControl.on('search:LocationFound', function(e) {
e.layer.openPopup().openOn(Map);
});
Map.addControl(searchControl);
```

I gave a look onto the leaflet-search.css and the js, but I can't figure out where it's defined and I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Screenshot showing the differences http://i65.tinypic.com/2a67frr.png

Comment: The search icon is set here: https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/master/src/leaflet-search.css#L62

It looks like the size is hardcoded. I'd look at the other Leaflet buttons and see if they use a different measure to determine their size.

Comment: Found it. 
Easy buttons has this bit

    .leaflet-touch .search-button {
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     line-height: 30px;
     }

I'll amend it so I get everything at the same size. What I don't get is why this is trigger on my laptop when I use Edge and Chrome and not with Firefox